# Installing ROCm in virtualenv linux error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm relatively new and am trying to install tensorflow (GPU) in my virtualenv. I've followed most of the steps on the website https://gpuopen.com/rocm-tensorflow-1-8-release/ and all have been fine except the last. When trying to install tensorflow, I get the error

> > (keras2) z@z-MS-7816:~/Documents/keras2$ pip3 install ./tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
> >
> > tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I've looked at the other threads and they mention that it has to be python 3.5? But that was over a year ago and I can't find any recent documentary regarding to the compatible python version. I'm currently using 3.6.7. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - you have to use python 3.5 with tensorflow 1.80! The solution was simple, install python 3.5 and fire up a virtualenv using python 3.5. Then install the tensorflow package.